# Importing contacts from Facebook

Tags: php

Are there any resources about importing facebook and twitter contacts using their own authentication (So that user supplies password on their own website).
Thank you for any help.
PS. I'm using PHP.

Comment: Yes, there are: http://developers.facebook.com/docs and http://dev.twitter.com/doc

Answer (score 0):

Try using OAuth (open authentication)

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

https://www.php.net/oauth